# teamsTab deep link not working in Microsoft Teams app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, deep-linking, microsoft-graph-teams

In our teams app we have two kind of tabs - one static and teamsTabs. ( A [teamsTab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamstab?view=graph-rest-beta) is a tab that's pinned (attached) to a channel within a team. There is a code that add it to a meeting and there is one tab per meeting. ) We want a button in the static tab to open one of the teamsTab. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamstab?view=graph-rest-beta#properties), we can find the webUrl, which is a deep link URL of the tab instance. But following this url does not navigate to the needed tab. It just reloads the current static tab. How can we make this work?

How we add the tab to a meeting:

```
      addAppTabToMeeting(accessToken: string, meetingId: string, appId: string): any {
        const signInDeferred = $.Deferred();
        const getMessageUrl = this.graphRestUrlBeta + "/chats/" + meetingId + "/tabs";
        const meetingData = {
          "displayName": "testapp",
          "teamsApp@odata.bind": this.graphRestUrlBeta + "/appCatalogs/teamsApps/" + appId,
          "configuration": {
            "entityId": meetingId.replace(/\W/g, ""),
            "contentUrl": ConfigHelper.getConfig("teamsBaseUri") + "content"
          }
        };
        fetch(getMessageUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }),
          body: JSON.stringify(meetingData)
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(meetings => {
            console.log(meetings);
            signInDeferred.resolve(meetings);
          });
        return signInDeferred.promise();
      }
```

Snippet from manifest.json:

```
"configurableTabs": [
    {
        "configurationUrl": "https://localhost:3000/config",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
        "scopes": [
            "groupchat"
        ],
        "context": [
            "meetingChatTab",
            "meetingDetailsTab",
            "meetingSidePanel"
        ]
    }
],
"staticTabs": [
    {
        "entityId": "testapp.create.meeting",
        "scopes": [
            "personal"
        ],
        "name": "Display name of tab",
        "contentUrl": "https://localhost:3000/intro"
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"devicePermissions": [
    "openExternal"
],
```

How the deep link is consumed:

```
{props.hearing.tabUrl && <Button content="Deep Link" onClick={()=>{
  if (props.hearing.tabUrl) microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(props.hearing.tabUrl);
}}/>}
```

Examples of obtained teamsTabs webUrls:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/b4eb8705-8e3a-4d17-be5c-5ffc3c2a26bf/_djb2_msteams_prefix_821ac114-71b2-4ae3-ad68-bafad1c54f1f?label=testapp&context=%7b%0d%0a++%22context%22%3a+%22chat%22%2c%0d%0a++%22chatId%22%3a+%2219%3ameeting_ZWI3YzhjOWEtNTYyMi00MjQ2LWJkNTEtOWEzYTM1YTAzNjhj%40thread.v2%22%2c%0d%0a++%22subEntityId%22%3a+null%0d%0a%7d&tenantId=1fa1032b-7875-4a35-aaf9-2cbfb3cd341b
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/b4eb8705-8e3a-4d17-be5c-5ffc3c2a26bf/_djb2_msteams_prefix_94ce4d73-9146-4a46-89ca-ddcdd8cc2c31?label=testapp&context=%7b%0d%0a++%22context%22%3a+%22chat%22%2c%0d%0a++%22chatId%22%3a+%2219%3ameeting_OTM1ZjFjNWItNTQxNS00MzcwLWI5NDctMjg4NzM3MTIyYzRl%40thread.v2%22%2c%0d%0a++%22subEntityId%22%3a+null%0d%0a%7d&tenantId=1fa1032b-7875-4a35-aaf9-2cbfb3cd341b
```

Edit 0: It is interesting that, if we replace "context" with "contextType" and use the resulting url in an empty browser tab, it opens the needed tab. But the following code, doesn't achieve the same result. A button click just reloads the current page.

```
{props.hearing.tabUrl && <Button content="Deep Link" onClick={()=>{
  if (props.hearing.tabUrl) microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(props.hearing.tabUrl.replace("%22context%22", "%22contextType%22"));
}}/>}
```

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a configurable tab added in a meeting?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT , yes, that is my aim.

Comment: Could you please try to get the tab link by navigating to Your Meeting tab >  'More options (...)' > 'Copy link to tab' and then try . It worked for us. The link will be in this format: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/da6eaf79-08f0-47d8-9e71-179a8589e546/_djb2_msteams_prefix_238113063?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22%3Anull%2C%22chatId%22%3A%2219%3Ameeting_YTU3MDAxZDYtNDFiMS00ZTVlLWJhYzEtNTg5MGJjNDlkZWI3%40thread.v2%22%2C%22contextType%22%3A%22chat%22%7D&tenantId=36a708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-0a5f7b7693df

Comment: Yes, but we don't need the link in a clipboard, we need to obtain it in the app. More over, I don't find a 'More options (...)' menu on our tab.

Comment: I've managed to find the 'More options (...)' menu. It really gives a correct url address of the tab. But we need to acquire the url in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the url as below and try. It worked in this way:

```
var contentUrl = "https://localhost:3000/intro";
var channelId = "19:meeting_ZWI3YzhjOWEtNTYyMi00MjQ2LWJkNTEtOWEzYTM1YTAzNjhj@thread.v2";
microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/b4eb8705-8e3a-4d17-be5c-5ffc3c2a26bf/_djb2_msteams_prefix_821ac114-71b2-4ae3-ad68-bafad1c54f1f?label=testapp&context={\"canvasUrl\":\"" + contentUrl + "\",\"channelId\":\"" + channelId + "\",\"subEntityId\":\"null\"}&tenantId=36a708ef-700d-4d60-9de0-0a5f7b7693df");
```